# Convert Postgres Query to JPQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpql

How to convert below PostreSQL query into JPQL? I mainly stuck with **row_number(), partition** and **when case**.

```
select p, c from  product p left join 
  (
    select 
    c.product_id, c.id, c.status, c.start_date,
    row_number() over (partition by product_id order by (case status when 'EXPIRED' then 2 else 1 end) asc, start_date desc) as row_number
    from contract c
    order by product_id
  ) c
  on
  p.id = c.product_id and c.row_number = 1 
  order by p.id, c.start_date;
```

Comment: May we see what you have so far?

Comment: select p,c from Product p LEFT JOIN 
(select c.product.id, c.status, c.startDate row_number() over (partition by product_id order by (case status when 'EXPIRED' then 2 else 1 end) asc, start_date desc) as row_number  from Contract c order by  c.product.id) c 
on p.id = c.product.id and c.row_number=1
order by p.id, c.startDate;

Comment: @NileshJadav I'm afraid it's not going to work. In JPQL you can only join entities (and not sub-queries) and only by a mapped relation-path (f.ex. *if* `Product` has `@ManyToOne` `Contract` on a `contract` property, you could use `... FROM Product p JOIN p.contract c ...` -- note that `ON` is ommitted). Also, window functions are not supported in JPQL.

Comment: @pozs many thanks for your information.

Comment: @NileshJadav although your problem seems to me a classic [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group?sort=votes) -- some of these solutions might be representable in JPQL.

Comment: @pozs again thanks a lot :)